# Using the remote branch instead of local branch in git

Tags: git

I want git to forget everything that I have edited in local branch, and want to pull the update from remote branch.

I did not know how to do that and I am getting merge conflicts on few files.

What should I do if I do not want to merge the files at all (local edits need to be deleted) and start new with the remote HEAD?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Supposing you are talking about changes done on `master` branch for instance:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard origin/master
git pull
```

You reset `master` `HEAD` on the one of `remote/master`, and then can fetch `remote/master` + merge it to local `master`.

Comment: This will do what's needed. Other solutions would be to git checkout every file you've modified locally, but git reset --hard will do that in one fell swoop.

Comment: What should I put instead of `origin/master` if I checked out branch `A/B` from `repo3:project1` ??

Comment: @user: it was only an example, based on your current branch which I assumed was `master`. Replace `master` by the name of your branch, supposing that same name exists on `remote`.

Comment: Oh, adding `origin/` in front of the branch name worked. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just delete your local copy, and reclone the remote?  That's effectively like deleting all your changes, without having to have local history for unwanted changes.

Comment: This is a very heavy-handed approach, but it works as a last resort.